# How to determine, how many number of digits 3 is in variable

Tags: c++

I have a variable which contains this numbers

```
int n = 6396339;
```

I need to determine how many digits 3 is in variable.
So far i trued like this:

```
int n = 6396339, counter = 0;

    while (n > 0)
    {
        if ((n % 10) % 3 == 0) {
            counter++;
        }
        n /= 10;
    }
    cout << counter << endl;
```

But this algorithm is not working correctly. Could you please help me to solve problem.

Comment: Remove the "C" tag, `cout <<` is not valid in C

Comment: _"this algorithm is not working correctly"_ is not an acceptable problem statement or question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(n % 10) % 3 == 0
```

is true for any digit that is divisible by three, i.e. `0`, `3`,  `6` and `9`. Just check whether the digit is equal to `3`:

```
(n % 10) == 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could print the number to a string, then traverse the string and check each character whether it is `'3'`.